# Quand doit-on commencer un mot par une majuscule (noms de mois, de lieux, etc.)?

Tags: orthographe, noms-propres, majuscules

Il semble que le choix entre commencer un mot par une majuscule et ne pas le faire est très confus. Par exemple, on écrit : *la France*, *le français* … *Paris*, *les parisiens*.

Quand doit-on commencer un mot par une majuscule en français ? Y a-t-il même un véritable consensus ? Cela varie-t-il géographiquement ?

Comment: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_des_majuscules_en_fran%C3%A7ais has all you need to know about that.

Comment: On met des majuscules aux noms propres et en tête de phrase, il y a des règles bien précises qu'il est inutile d'exposer ici. Il peut y avoir quelques cas difficiles avec certaines locutions, mais ce genre de question serait à poser au cas par cas.

Comment: To those who are voting to close for 'too localized': how is this too localized, exactly?  Isn't it a standard throughout the francophone world as to how and where one should capitalize words?

Comment: A noter: on ne dit pas "le Paris", mais "Paris" tout court.

Comment: I suggest we reopen this question because it's a totally valid one. I don't see how it could be considered localized. For future references, if you think it's too localized, add a comment with some appropriate remarks as why you think it is too localized.

Comment: Ah, je m'attendais à cette question :-) Comme dit Gilles, il existe des règles bien précises concernant l'emploi des capitales et des majuscules (qui sont différentes et souvent interverties...), voir notamment http://www.albin-michel.fr/La-Majuscule-c-est-capital--EAN=9782226143891

Comment: Nous avons juste discuté dans le chat si on doit écrire "les québecois" ou "les Québecois", alors je pense que cette question reste pertinente et intéressante.

Comment: On dit les Québ**é**cois :)

Comment: Grr, silly accents.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Les **noms** de mois, de jours de la semaine, **n'ont pas** de majuscule:

> Je suis né le 17 août. Aujourd'hui on est jeudi.

Les **noms** de lieux **ont** une majuscule:

> Je veux aller au Québec. La ville de Montréal m'attire beaucoup.

Les **noms** pour décrire les personnes d'une certaine nationalité **ont** une majuscule:

> Je connais une Algérienne très sympa.

Les **adjectifs** qui viennent de nationalités **n'ont pas** de majuscule:

> Il est français.

Les **noms** de langue **n'ont pas** de majuscule:

> Je parle anglais et français.