# Doit-on écrire « Je suis français » ou « Je suis Français »?

Tags: adjectifs, majuscules

Les noms propres ont une majuscule en français standard, tandis que les adjectifs dérivés de ces noms n'en ont pas : *La plupart des Français vivent dans la République française*. Dans la phrase *je suis français*, ce n'est pas clair si *français* est un nom ou un adjectif. On peut par exemple dire « Je suis peintre » ou « je suis professeur », ainsi que « je suis blond » et « je suis grand ».

Mes deux questions sont donc les suivantes :

- Quelle sorte de mot est *français* dans la phrase *Je suis français* ?
- Faut-il mettre une majuscule à ce mot dans cette phrase?

Le Ngram obligatoire est très intéressant : la majuscule domine jusqu'aux années 70, alors qu'aujourd'hui les deux formes s'emploient côte à côte.[image]

Comment: Je ne peux pas t'aider, je suis Belge

Comment: Es-tu Belge ou belge ?

Comment: @M'vy pas vraiment, la question porte ici sur le choix du substantif ou de l'adjectif ; il est très clair que l'un prend la majuscule et pas l'autre.

Comment: @Vincent si j'étais cohérent avec ma propre réponse, je serais belge. Va comprendre. En fait, je suis Incohérent.

Comment: Juste suggéré un duplicate possible [Quand doit-on commencer un mot par une majuscule](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/64)

Comment: Le conditionnel dans le titre m'irrite un peu. J'ai le droit de le remplacer par l'indicatif ?

Comment: @Stéphane : Vous, les francophones, avez toujours le droit de modifier tout ce que je mets sur ce site si c'est fait dans l'intention de transformer mon baragouinage en français ^^

Comment: Tu blagues?? Ton français est vraiment parfait, donc j'osais pas trop ! Puis ce n'est qu'un détail très très mineur. (On emploie « devrait-on » lorsqu'on suggère de remplacer une phrase qui a été mentionnée avant par « je suis français » ou « je suis Français ». Ici, le choix ne concerne que ces deux possibilités. Donc, pas de conditionnel, c'est forcément l'une ou l'autre.)

Comment: Merci de m'avoir appris cette nuance, que je ne connaissais pas.

Et au fait, j'ai peut-être un niveau [confirmé](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/490/existe-t-il-un-mot-pour-le-niveau-entre-intermediaire-et-avance) de français, mais « vraiment parfait » n'est qu'une exagération presque fantastique. Merci tout de même pour tes paroles aimables. :)

Comment: Ton graphique illustre bien la résurgence de nationalisme pendant la première guerre mondiale et son absence pendant la seconde.

Comment: @Knu : Bien vu !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bon après ce fail matinal de question dupliquée, voici une meilleure analyse.

Les deux formes sont correctes. Il y a un longue explication sur les Gentilés dans [cet article de Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9).

> On peut souvent utiliser l’adjectif aussi bien que le gentilé : « Je suis français » est tout aussi correct que « Je suis Français. »

Cela permet aussi de faire des distinctions

> un savant allemand, qui est un savant de nationalité allemande,
>
> un savant Allemand, c'est-à-dire un Allemand qui sait beaucoup de choses

Après possible que l'usage change en fonction des époques et peut-être de la manière de l'enseigner.

Comment: Tiens, je m'aperçois que je prononce « un savant allemand » mais « un savant-t-Allemand. » Suis-je le seul ?

Comment: En général je dis: "Un Allemand savant" donc la liaison... mais sinon, je n'ai jamais fais la liaison dans l'autre cas. Peut-être que je n'utilise que l'adjectif :P

Comment: Axioplase : je ne trouve pas les expressions assez idiomatiques pour vraiment te répondre, mais il est certain que ce genre de liaison dépendant du sens existe. Dans sa *Grammaire critique du français*, Wilmet fait remarquer qu'en prononçant « un marchand de draps anglais, » on fera ou pas la liaison suivant que ce sont les draps ou le marchand qui (est|sont) anglais...

Comment: @Axioplase: J'ai eu la même réaction. Je vais la liaison lorsqu'il s'agit de l'Allemand qui est savant, mais pas dans le premier cas.

Answer (score 11):

Manifestement, il a été répondu qu'il fallait mettre la majuscule à [d'autres qui ont posé la question](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic9238-je-suis-francais-un-francais-majuscule-ou-minuscule.html).

Pour ma part, je préfèrerais la minuscule, parce qu'il me semble qu'il est plus naturel de le considérer comme adjectif dans ce cas-là, d'autant que le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fran%C3%A7ais) liste l'exemple *Être français de naissance ou français de cœur.*

Answer (score 5):

Selon Grévisse (*Le bon usage*, 15e édition, 2011, § 99-3e, p. 96), « si le mot est un attribut sans article, on a le choix, selon qu'on le prend pour un adjectif ou pour un nom […] » de mettre ou non la majuscule, et Grévisse d'encourager la préférence donnée à la majuscule…

L'Académie française et le TLF, entre autres, sont d'un avis contraire. En fait, je crois, pour préserver les subtilités de notre langue, qu'il faut distinguer les noms auxquels correspond un adjectif (qui doit être l’attribut) et les autres noms (qui peuvent être attributs, faute d’adjectif correspondant).

En effet, si l'on dit : « Il est médecin » et « C'est un médecin », c'est exactement la même chose. Mais, si l'on dit : « Il est brave » et « C'est un brave », on perçoit une nuance : dans le premier cas, il s'agit d'exprimer une qualité (adjectif qualificatif) tandis que, dans le second, on désigne une personne (nom) en l'assimilant à une qualité.

De même, il y a une nuance entre « Il est français » (adjectif qualificatif), comme lorsqu’on dit : « Il est grand », et « C'est un Français » (nom qui désigne une personne qu’on assimile à sa nationalité), comme lorsqu’on dit : « Voilà un Français ».

Answer (score 2):

Pour information, je cite [J.-P. Lacroux](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/pacte-point.html#Peuple), p. 276 de l'édition papier :

> On nous explique parfois que dans : « Je suis Français », l’attribut
>   du sujet est un adjectif (ellipse : « Je suis [un citoyen, un
>   ressortissant] français ») et qu’il convient par conséquent d’écrire
>   [« Je suis français »] comme on écrit : « Je suis débile ». C’est bien
>   sûr inexact ; l’attribut est un substantif, comme dans : je suis
>   marin, elle est boulangère, etc.
>
> [ *Orthotypo* - Orthographe & Typographie françaises, *Dictionnaire raisonné*, ed. Quintette ]

Il renvoie à la suite à J. Hanse (Nouveau Dictionnaire des difficultés du français moderne) et à Jean Dumont ([Vade-Mecum du typographe](https://archive.org/details/vademecumdutypog00dumo), 1915).

[L'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#6_strong-em-adjectif-ou-nom-de-nationalit-il-est-franais-ou-il-est-franais-em-strong), par exemple, n'est pas de cet avis.

Answer (score 0):

Dans la phrase « je suis française » le mot *française* est un adjectif, et un homme dit « je suis français » le mot *français* est également un adjectif.

Comment: Donc avec les minuscules ?  C'est ça aussi la question.

Comment: *− Dites à vos amis combien j'aime la France ; qu'ils sachent bien que **je suis Française**. Je vous charge particulièrement de dire cela*, Chateaubriand, *Mémoires d'outre-tombe*.