# Peut-on dire « je suis Français », « je suis peintre », etc.?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, noms

En lisant [Doit-on écrire « Je suis français » ou « Je suis Français »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/958), je me suis posé la question suivante : « est-ce que la phrase "je suis peintre" est correcte ? »

Il me paraît sûr que la phrase incriminée est courante, mais ne devrait-on pas plutôt dire « je suis *un* peintre » ?
Autrement dit, je me demande si après ce verbe *être*, il est bien raisonnable de mettre un nom sans article, pronom, …

Je n'ai pas d'exemple non-idiomatique convaincant où un nom suive le verbe être comme ici…
Suis-je trop fatigué pour construire un tel exemple évident, ai-je oublié une règle de grammaire apprise durant ma jeunesse, ou êtes vous aussi maintenant dans le doute ?

Comment: C'est vrai que si la réponse à cette question-ci était négative, cela voudrait dire d'office que _je suis français_ est la forme correcte.

Comment: Voir aussi [Pourquoi quelqu'un a dit, "Je suis pilote" mais, on n'a pas dit "Je suis UN pilote"?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2096)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La forme *je suis peintre* est correcte<sup>1</sup>.

Voir la [définition du verbe *être* du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre), 2<sup>ème</sup> section, I. a. 2. a) β). (ou chercher « blanchisseuse »)

Malheureusement, je n'y vois rien sur le cas où l'adjectif est un gentilé ; mais j'imagine qu'on peut estimer par extension que c'est correct également.

<sup>1. Sauf quand le sujet n'est pas peintre.</sup>

Comment: +1 for the footnote.

Answer (score 8):

La forme « Je suis peintre » est correcte et signifie que ma profession est peintre.
La forme  « Je suis un peintre » me semble incomplète, on ajoutera un adjectif ou autre pour souligner un trait particulier du peintre: « Je suis un peintre célèbre » ou « Je suis un peintre en mal d'inspiration ».

Comment: Pour moi, l'ajout du déterminant peut aussi être une manière de mettre en valuer sa profession, pour se grandir: _Je n'ai pas de temps à perdre avec vous, je suis un diplomate, moi, monsieur_.

Comment: Ton exemple n'est pas très convaincant : « je suis diplomate » voudrait de toute façon dire autre chose...

Comment: Je n'y avais pas pensé, mais tu soulèves en effet un point intéressant. Peut-être que l'article est alors plutôt utilisé dans les cas où une confusion est possible?

Answer (score 3):

Je ne suis pas assez grammairien pour te répondre sans chercher dans des références.

Grevisse note que « le nom [utilisé comme attribut] sans déterminant se rapproche de l'adjectif. [...] Il peut dans certains cas recevoir, comme l'adjectif, des marques de degré. »

Comment: De toutes façons, on veut des références :-)

Comment: [reference needed]

Comment: Parfois c'est à se demander si on cherche des réponses à nos questions, ou si on veut engager une femme de chambre.

Comment: Il y a des gens qui sont à la recherche de questions auxquelles répondre, d'autres qui cherchent des réponses à leurs questions. SE est une bourse d'échange entre les deux.