# Quelle figure de style consiste-t-elle à faire référence à un antécédent inattendu?

Tags: figure-de-style, pronoms

Dans un [commentaire à propos d'une réponse à une autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/965), je n'ai pas pu résister à l'envie d'écrire :

- Je faisais référence au fait d'en demander.

Alors que je voulais dire:

- Je faisais référence au fait de demander des références.

Même si il s'agit du même mot, l'utilisation de *référence* comme antécédent de *en* est pour le moins incongrue et, comme le montre le commentaire suivant, pas facile à comprendre.

Un autre exemple, tiré de mémoire d'une bande dessinée:

- J'en ai marre qu'on passe son temps à le perdre ! (*le* pour *le temps*)

Doit-on considérer dans ces exemples que l'antécédent est en fait invalide, et que ces tournures relèvent plutôt de la figure de style que d'un bon français ? Si oui, comment cette figure de style s'appelle-t-elle ?

Comment: J'aime beaucoup ta question et la réponse que tu lui as apportée. En revanche, je trouve le titre assez trompeur : l'antécédant n'est pas « invalide, » il est simplement utilisé dans un autre sens...

Comment: C'est la seule formulation qui m'est venue en tête au moment ou j'ai posé la question. Je suis ouvert à remplacer _invalide_ par autre chose ; que proposerais-tu?

Comment: Euh... Incongru ?

Comment: Peut-être pas dans un titre, mais tu m'as fait trouver plus simple: _inattendu_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En cherchant moi-même, je suis aussi tombé sur l'[antanaclase elliptique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclase).

La citation de Coluche est assez similaire :

- *Les gardiens de la paix, au lieu de la garder, ils feraient mieux de nous la foutre.*

Par contre, il me semble que l'antanaclase sous-entend que le mot doit avoir une signification différente dans ses deux emplois, ce que je ne retrouve pas dans l'exemple *passer son temps à le perdre* (*temps* ayant la même [signification](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/temps) dans *perdre son temps* et *passer son temps*).

Dans l'exemple *je faisais référence au fait d'en demander*, les deux [significations](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence) de *référence* sont effectivement distinctes, mêmes si elles sont proches.

Manifestement la [différence entre zeugma et antanaclase elliptique](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic23141-zeugme-et-antanaclase.html) est assez ténue ; d'ailleurs wikipedia les considère également comme proches.

Pour conclure, je dirais que ma question était mal posée parce que les deux exemples sont en fait des figures différentes:

- *J'en ai marre qu'on passe son temps à le perdre !* — zeugma
- *Je faisais référence au fait d'en demander.* — antanaclase elliptique

Comment: Évidemment, tu as raison. En revanche, je trouve surprenant que les stylisticiens n'aient pas façonné un mot spécial pour ton « antanaclase elliptique. » Cela change tout de même assez violemment la saveur de la figure.

Comment: J'avoue que j'aime assez que ce soit en deux mots. Je trouve ça pédant en diable.

Comment: Ah oui, aussi !

Answer (score 4):

C'est un [zeugme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_%28stylistique%29) !

En effet, un zeugme est une figure de style qui utilise un terme (que j'appellerai le pivot) dans deux contextes différents, les deux contextes étant souvent liés par une conjonction de coordination dans la même phrase. On a l'habitude de voir des zeugmes utilisant un verbe comme pivot, par exemple :

> Je vais au casino et me ruiner.

Le verbe *aller* est utilisé dans cette phrase comme signifiant du déplacement vers le casino et comme auxiliaire de futur de la ruine prochaine.

Dans le cas de la question, le pivot est le nom *référence*.

> Je faisais référence au fait d'en demander.

*Référence* est là un pivot car il articule les deux idées indépendantes :

- rappeler un élément précédent du discours (*faire référence*)
- l'objet de la requête faite par le locuteur (*demander des références*)

Ce n'est que la structure syntaxique du Français qui force l'utilisation de *en* comme rappel au mot *référence* (seule expansion possible quand le contexte de la phrase ne permet pas d'épandre ce *en* en autre chose). Le *en* sert d'ailleurs aussi à lisser la difficulté représentée par le fait que dans une des expressions, *référence* est au singulier, et dans l'autre il est au pluriel.

Comment: Hmmm... j'y avais pensé, mais je ne suis qu'à moitié convaincu.

Comment: Un zeugme est couramment articulé autour d'un verbe, mais rien dans sa définition n'implique que l'articulation soit sur un verbe. Dans l'exemple donné dans la question, l'articulation est autour d'un nom. La structure est la même.

Comment: Tu pourrais développer ta réponse un peu? Au moins expliquer en quoi l'expression est un zeugme?

Comment: Moi, quand mon médecin me dit que j'ai un zeugme, je ne cherche pas à en savoir davantage.

Answer (score 3):

A mon humble avis, ça reste une figure de style. Si elle est volontaire, pas de problème. En revanche, si tu veux que ça passe inaperçu, que ça sonne juste, essaye plutôt de trouver un synonyme.

> Je parlais du fait de demander des références.
>
> Je faisais référence au fait de demander des sources d'information.

Ou alors, tu veux accentuer le mot référence.

> Je faisais référence au fait d'en demander, des références.

Comment: C'était effectivement volontaire, mais ça mérite d'être signalé.

Comment: Une aussi jolie figure, ça ne mérite pas de se cacher…

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que le problème vient surtout du contexte. En conjuguant à l'imparfait, tu indiques que tu parles d'une chose passée. Ainsi le lecteur va chercher dans le "en" une référence à un élément passsé. La construction est correcte!

> -Je crois que demander ces informations est illégal!
>
> -Oui tu as raison, ces informations sont illégales tu ne peux les posséder.
>
> -Je faisais référence au fait d'en demander

Ici "en" réfère à "information".

Au final, on a juste une phrase ambigüe.

Pour avoir une figure de style on aurait pu faire:

> Je fais référence au fait d'en demander, en as tu ?

Qui est alors une phrase autoréférente (ou potentiellement ambigüe si on considère que en réfère à autre chose, mais le présent suggère que non).

Answer (score -1):

Je pense que ton deuxième exemple est une [antiphrase](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiphrase). Quant aux références il me semble que « en » fait référence au contexte du commentaire, donc « aux références demandées » et non pas à « la référence ».