# Problème ou problématique

Tags: choix-de-mot, standard, jargon

Titre d'[une note de blog](http://questionsdegenerations.nordblogs.com/archive/2011/09/08/les-solidarites-problematique-centrale-de-la-crise-financier.html)

> Les solidarités, problématique centrale de la crise financière

J'entends et je lis de plus en plus, en particulier chez les journalistes et les hommes politiques employer *problématique* alors que je dirais simplement *problème*.

D'après le TLF

> Problématique II. −Subst. fém.
>   B. −Ensemble des problèmes qui se posent sur un sujet déterminé

Ça semble convenir pour des usages façon « dans la problématique de la crise financière », mais « problématique centrale » ?

Cet usage de *problématique* peut-il être considéré comme standard ? Pour mémoire, l'[Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/probl%C3%A9matique) ne reconnaît même pas *problématique* comme substantif.

Et comment cet usage est-il perçu ? Est-il typique du style politique ou journalistique ? Sonne-t-il naturel ou pédant ?

Comment: En résumé : « L'usage abusif de _problématique_ [le](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1004) devient. »

Comment: Hélas ce sont pour beaucoup les journalistes qui répandent la langue à la mode ! Comment les pousser à ne pas utiliser ce glissement sémantique, au moins les journalistes des tv et radios d' État ?

Comment: Un problème se résoud alors qu'une problématique se solutionne.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Il y a des effets de mode sur des mots ou des expressions, en effet. Le mot *sociétal* en est un autre, et on l'utilise souvent là où on parlerait plutôt d'un problème "banalement" social, mais le mot sonne plus recherché.

La problématique a néanmoins un aspect différent du problème, puisque la problématique est le cadre dans le quel se pose le problème (le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/probl%C3%A9matique) parle aussi de la problématique comme d'un terme épistémologique signifiant "art, science de poser les problèmes"). Il y a donc un aspect englobant, plus large, que dans le mot *problème*, raison probable du goût politico-journalistique pour ce mot : là où un problème se doit d'être bien défini pour pouvoir être résolu, la problématique peut être un ensemble flou de règles externes au problème, et ne pas avoir de bornes bien définies.

Pour répondre aux questions précises :

> Cet usage de *problématique* peut-il être considéré comme standard ?

Standard, certainement pas. C'est un glissement sémantique malheureux qu'il faut combattre avec tout l'acharnement possible ! Si l'usage finit par s'imposer, on pourra au moins dire qu'on aura mené bataille.

> Et comment cet usage est-il perçu ? Est-il typique du style politique ou journalistique ?

Je pense bien l'avoir entendu dans le cadre entrepreneurial aussi.

> Sonne-t-il naturel ou pédant ?

Je ne le trouve pas naturel, mais je peux le tolérer lorsque le locuteur est manifestement embêté et essaie d'éviter une lourdeur en répétant *problème* trop souvent. Je le prendrais dans ce cas comme une forme de métonymie. Si le locuteur répète avec fierté l'utilisation, pleinement conscient d'essayer de noyer un poisson, c'est pire que pédant, c'est médiocre.

Dans le cas de la note de blog citée, une bonne alternative est utilisée par l'auteur lui-même, qui parle aussi de *thématique* dans le corps du texte. Le *Trésor* nous dit pour ce mot : "qui pose ou qui est posé comme objet de l'activité mentale, soit implicitement ou sur le mode non réfléchi, soit explicitement ou sur le mode réfléchi", ce qui me semble être bien plus proche de la signification souhaitée.

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui suit renvoie à http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=182638 :

De l'Office québécois de la langue française, 2005:

> "Dans la langue courante, il peut arriver que problématique et problème soient confondus, mais le terme problématique sous-entend généralement une pluralité de problèmes."

**De l'utilisateur jester. :** Cette explication me plaît, cependant je voudrais ajouter quelque chose : à mon avis, problème est plus concret que problématique. Si on parle d'un problème, on se réfère à un problème concret; si on parle d'une problématique, on parle de plusieurs problèmes, comme Jumot a déjà dit.

**De l'utilisateur Chimel. :** Il y a aussi aujourd'hui une tendance (assez contestable) à remplacer un mot simple par un soi-disant synonyme plus compliqué et qui fait plus sérieux: problématique au lieu de problème, méthodologie au lieu de méthode...

Dans la pratique, "une problématique complexe" signifie donc souvent et simplement "un problème complexe".

Pour s'en enquérir plus : http://www.protic.net/profs/melanie/problematique.htm