# Est-ce qu'une clause négative sans sujet est valide ?

Tags: grammaire, sujet, constructions

Dans [cet article](http://www.lemonde.fr/cgi-bin/ACHATS/acheter.cgi?offre=ARCHIVES&type_item=ART_ARCH_30J&objet_id=1176492&xtmc=qui_veut_gouter_la_patee_pour_chats&xtcr=1), il y a une section qui contient ceci :

> [...] goûteur pour chats. Mais ne le devient pas qui veut.

Je ne comprends pas la grammaire de la deuxième phrase ; il n'y a aucun sujet, juste une construction “ne … pas” au début ?  Est-ce que c'est la bonne grammaire, ou pas ?  Est-ce que le sujet est implicite ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Le sujet de la phrase est « qui veut », c'est la même chose par exemple dans :

> Qui vole un œuf, vole un bœuf

Où le sujet est « qui vole un œuf ».

Par contre, le rejet du sujet en fin de phrase est plus étonnant, mais s'explique ici parce qu'il serait ambigu si placé au début de la phrase (vu qu'on ne sait pas encore ce qu'il veut).

Mais c'est une construction classique, dont voici quelques exemples courants:

> Sauve qui peut !
>   Advienne que pourra !
>   Rira bien, qui rira le dernier.

Comment: N'est-ce pas à rapprocher de l'antanaclase elliptique ? Peut-être suis-je induit en erreur par ma toute récente lecture de [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/quelle-figure-de-style-consiste-t-elle-a-faire-reference-a-un-antecedent-inatten) ? Il m'a semblé y voir une analogie de forme...