# Pourquoi quelqu'un a dit « Je suis pilote », et pas « Je suis UN pilote » ?

Tags: grammaire, noms, articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Peut-on dire « je suis Français », « je suis peintre », etc.?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/962/peut-on-dire-je-suis-francais-je-suis-peintre-etc)

Pour pratiquer le français, mes amis et moi nous partageons des vidéos de français à l'occasion.

J'ai regardé un film pour enfants, où une femme s'est présentée.
La femme a dit : « Je suis pilote. »

Pourquoi n'a-t-elle pas dit : « Je suis UN pilote », mais « Je suis pilote » ? Est-ce que les deux formes sont acceptables ?

<sub>(Pardonnez mon français, maintenant j'essaie toujours d'améliorer mon français. Si vous remarquez des erreurs dans ma question, pouvez-vous les corriger s'il vous plaît ?)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui, les deux formes sont acceptables mais ont une signification légèrement différente.

- « Je suis pilote » peut être traduit par « *I am a pilot* ».
- Alors que « Je suis un pilote » signifie « *I am one pilot* ».

Exemple dans des phrases :

> — Et vous, que faites-vous dans la vie ?
>   — Je suis pilote.
>   — Vous avez volé au-dessus du Triangle des Bermudes ?
>   — Bien sûr, je suis un pilote qui n'a peur de rien !

En anglais :

> — What about you, what do you do?
>   — I'm a pilot.
>   — Have you flown over the Bermuda Triangle?
>   — Of course, I am one pilot who is afraid of nothing!

Comment: J'aime bien. Seulement pas sur pour la dernière phrase qui serait très probablement traduite: `I am a fearless pilot`. Et je n'utiliserai probablement pas `one pilot` pour faire la phrase ici. Mais l'idée reste juste.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse :D

Est-ce que cet usage de "un" le même pour les autres métiers? 

Pour exemple, "Je suis médecin", "Je suis un médecin".

Cependant, je pense que pour moi, c'est plus simple à dire "Je suis un pilote", comme en anglais, "I am a pilot".

Comment: @ViktorChynarov Oui, on omet l'article pour tous les métiers. « Je suis professeur de français », « je suis vendeur de voitures », « je suis cireur de chaussures », « je suis directeur d'agence », ... Et aussi « je suis retraité », « je suis étudiant », « je suis chômeur », ...