# Savant versus grognard

Tags: expressions, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Inspiré par [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/958/doit-on-dire-je-suis-francais-ou-je-suis-francais/966#966), je me demandais pourquoi puis-je dire *un savant Allemand* mais pas *un grognard Français** ?

Sachant que *un grognard **de** Français* et *un Français grognard* sonnent mieux, la syllabe finale de l'adjectif aurait-elle une incidence sur l'emploi d'une épithète antéposée ?

<sub>* l'adjectif donc, bien que dans l'absolu pendant une reconstitution un grognard pourrait être d'une autre nationalité.</sub>

Comment: Si personne ne trouve une raison valable vous pourrez clore la question as duplicate of http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je ne pense pas que la terminaison '-ard' joue quelque rôle que ce soit. En faisant des essais avec des adjectifs plus courants tels que *bavard*, *débrouillard*, *revanchard*, *rigolard*, *vantard* (merci au TLF), je m'aperçois qu'ils s'insèrent aisément dans des phrases antéposés à par exemple *personnage*, *énergumène*. Et même *grognard* !

Mais on est là dans des usages particuliers de la langue (poésie, rhétorique, pastiche) qui permettent l'effet de style de l'inversion de la place normale de l'adjectif. Il y a donc toujours une part d'appréciation personnelle dans ce qui est, non pas correct, mais acceptable, plaisant, piquant, surprenant ; le contexte joue un grand rôle. Par exemple, de telles expressions seraient tout à fait à leur place dans un discours gaullien enflammé.

Quant au *grognard Français*, voyons si on pourrait le rendre acceptable : "Quant au grincheux Gaulois, nul archétype ne fut plus colporté au long des âges. Oui, chers compatriotes ! Il est temps de remiser aux poubelles de l'histoire la triste figure du grognard Français, ce vil homme de paille dressé par les ennemis de la nation !" ;)

Comment: Excellente ta citation improvisée!

Answer (score 8):

C'est une question de [position de l'adjectif](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom). L'adjectif *[savant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savant)* peut se placer avant le nom ; le sens n'en est pas tout à fait le même.¹ L'adjectif *grognard* ne peut se placer qu'après. On peut donc dire :

- *un Allemand savant* (un habitant d'Allemagne qui est érudit)
- *un allemand savant* (une langue allemande très châtiée)
- *un savant Allemand* (un habitant d'Allemagne qui est particulièrement érudit)
- *un savant allemand* (une maîtrise très pousée de la langue allemande)
- *un savant allemand* (un scientifique qui vient d'Allemagne ; ici *savant* est le nom et *allemand* l'adjectif)

On pourrait tout autant remplacer *allemand* par *français* dans ces exemples. Comme les adjectifs *grognard* et *français* ne peuvent se placer qu'après le nom, les possibilités sont plus limitées avec *grognard* :

- un grognard français (un soldat qui vient de France)
- un Français grognard (un habitant de France qui grogne souvent)
- un français grognard (la langue française qui grogne, c'est grammaticalement valable mais je ne vois pas ce que ça peut vouloir dire)

<sub>¹ Pour une personne, je dirais que l'adjectif postposé (*homme savant*) est plutôt neutre alors que l'adjectif antéposé (*savant homme*) a tendance à être laudatif ; je renvoie à l'[article du Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savant) pour une exploration des différents sens.</sub>

Comment: "L'adjectif grognard ne peut se placer qu'après" > Pourquoi?

Comment: @Knu Les adjectifs sont par défaut après le nom. Certains peuvent se placer avant, mais c'est essentiellement au cas par cas. Lis [la question que je cite](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/319/quand-peut-on-mettre-un-adjectif-avant-ou-apres-un-nom). Il se trouve que *savant* est un des nombreux cas particuliers qui peut aller avant ou après, alors que *grognard* suit le cas général.

Comment: Désolé en gros tu réponds à ma question par "c'est comme ça". Va falloir faire mieux ou alors m'expliquer en quoi *savant* est différent. Je n'ai pas pris grognard par hasard, comme *savant* il peut être aussi un nom et donc l'inversion devrait être possible car utile.

Comment: Parfois, « c'est comme ça, » hein ! :)

Comment: Bête question, quand _savant_ est avant _allemand_, doit-on faire la liaison? J'ai l'impression que non quand _savant_ est le nom et que oui quand il est adjectif. Correct?

Comment: @Joubarc Spontanément, je suis d'accord, mais pourquoi ? Après vérification sur [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(linguistique)%23Liaison_interdite), on fait toujours la liaison d'un adjectif sur un nom et jamais d'un nom vers un adjectif. L'article donne justement *savant anglais* comme exemple de cas où l'orthographe est la même mais la prononciation permet de distinguer les deux sens.